# Добавление к функции в JQuery автоматического переключения слайдов

Tags: jquery

```
var main = function() {

$('.arrow-next').click(function () {

    var currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
    var nextSlide = currentSlide.next();
    var currentDot = $('.active-dot');
    var nextDot = currentDot.next();

    if(nextSlide.length == 0) {
        nextSlide = $('.slide').first();
        nextDot = $('.dot').first();
    }           

    currentSlide.fadeOut(600).removeClass('active-slide');
    nextSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('active-slide');

    currentDot.removeClass('active-dot');
    nextDot.addClass('active-dot');

});

$('.arrow-prev').click(function () {
    var currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
    var prevSlide = currentSlide.prev();
    var currentDot = $('.active-dot');
    var prevDot = currentDot.prev();

    if(prevSlide.length == 0) {
        prevSlide = $('.slide').last();
        prevDot = $('.dot').last();
    }

    currentSlide.fadeOut(600).removeClass('active-slide');
    prevSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('active-slide');

    currentDot.removeClass('active-dot');
    prevDot.addClass('active-dot');
});
```

};

$(document).ready(main);

Как в данной функции создать не только ручное переключение слайдов, но и автоматическое (например каждые 20секунд) ?

Comment: Добавить таймер, который будет выполнять перелистывание.

Comment: могли бы вы подсказать, что нужно добавить в коде ? я не особо разбираюсь в JQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Автоматическая прокрутка действует до первого ручного вызова прокрутки.

```
var main = function() {
    var nextPageF = function () {
        var currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
        var nextSlide = currentSlide.next();
        var currentDot = $('.active-dot');
        var nextDot = currentDot.next();

        if(nextSlide.length == 0) {
            nextSlide = $('.slide').first();
            nextDot = $('.dot').first();
        }           

        currentSlide.fadeOut(600).removeClass('active-slide');
        nextSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('active-slide');

        currentDot.removeClass('active-dot');
        nextDot.addClass('active-dot');
    };

    var prefPageF = function () {
        var currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
        var prevSlide = currentSlide.prev();
        var currentDot = $('.active-dot');
        var prevDot = currentDot.prev();

        if(prevSlide.length == 0) {
            prevSlide = $('.slide').last();
            prevDot = $('.dot').last();
        }

        currentSlide.fadeOut(600).removeClass('active-slide');
        prevSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('active-slide');

        currentDot.removeClass('active-dot');
        prevDot.addClass('active-dot');
    };

    var interval = setInterval(nextPageF, 20000);
    $('.arrow-next').click(function(){
        clearInterval(interval );
        nextPageF();
    });
    $('.arrow-prev').click(function(){
        clearInterval(interval );
        prefPageF();
    });
};
```

Comment: Все работает, спасибо )
А могли бы Вы еще подсказать как сделать так, чтобы нажимая на определенный дот, открывался соответствующий слайд ?